# Hide sidebar for particular page in Mobile Angular Ui.(Angular Js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mobile-angular-ui

I am using mobile angular ui. I want to hide side for particular page.

> http://mobileangularui.com/

This side bar by default put in every page. But i don't want this side bar in home page. Mobile angular ui have one index.html file. One sidebar.html import in index file. And every page import in index file. But when come home.html file will come then sidebar should be hide. 
Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>y</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="yes" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.min.css" />

    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
  .color-winni-text
  {
    color:#c62222;
  }
  </style>
  <body ng-app="Y" ng-controller="MainController">

    <!-- Sidebars -->
    <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"
            ui-track-as-search-param='true'
            class="sidebar sidebar-left">
    </div>

    <div class="app">

      <!-- Navbars -->

      <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-top">
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center " ui-yield-to="title">
          <a class="color-winni-text" href="#/"> <strong>Winni Celebration</strong></a> 
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group pull-left">
          <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarLeft" class="btn sidebar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars  color-winni-text fa-2x"></i> 
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right" ui-yield-to="navbarAction">
          <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarRight" class="btn">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in color-winni-text"></i> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-bottom">
        <div class="btn-group justified">
          <a style="color:#c62222" href="#/" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-home fa-navbar"></i> Home</a>
          <a style="color:#c62222" href="#/my-winni" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-github fa-navbar"></i> My Winni</a>
          <a style="color:#c62222" href="https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui/issues" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-navbar"></i> Issues</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- App Body -->
      <div class="app-body background-color-body" style="background-color:white"  ui-prevent-touchmove-defaults>
        <div class="app-content scrollable-content">
          <ng-view></ng-view>  
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- ~ .app -->

    <div ui-yield-to="modals"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screen Shot of index file
[image]

App.js File.

```
angular.module('Y', [
  'ngRoute',
  'mobile-angular-ui',
  'Y.controllers.Main'
])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'home.html',  reloadOnSearch: null})
                .when('/cityPage', {templateUrl:'cityPage.html', reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/category-prduct', {templateUrl:'category-prduct.html',  reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/product-description', {templateUrl:'product-description.html',  reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/my-winni', {templateUrl:'my-winni.html',  reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/gift-box', {templateUrl:'gift-box.html',  reloadOnSearch: false});
});
```

I want to hide sidebar only on home.html page.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `<div ng-include="'sidebar.html'">` element in an [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive that examines the location path.

You can inject the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service into your `MainController` and expose the value of `$location.path()` to the template.

Example: `$scope.currentPath = $location.path()`

Then use:

```
<div ng-if="currentPath !== ''">
  <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'">`
```

Also, [use the controllerAs](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) syntax instead of `$scope`.

Comment: can you explain me more about $scope.currentPath = $location.path(). What should i do in controller

Comment: If you are attaching variables to $scope, which I assume you are since you are not using ng-controller="MainController as vm" syntax, then you should just do what I suggested in my example and add $scope.currentPath = $location.path() somewhere in your MainController. Be sure to inject the $location service also.